# How to get "feeCalculator` since "getRecentBlockhash()" deprecated?

Tags: web3.js, javascript, client, fee

This is how `feeCalculator` is received before:

```
const { feeCalculator } = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
```

`getRecentBlockhash()` is deprecated. Instead we use

```
  connection.getLatestBlockhash()
```

I checked this new api and could not find how to get `feeCalculator`. [Docs](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/interfaces/FeeCalculator.html) just says it is deprecated but does not show what to use instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little harder to use than the fee calculator, but the idea is to use `getFeeForMessage` instead, ie:

```
    const accountFrom = Keypair.generate();
    const accountTo = Keypair.generate();

    const { blockhash, ... } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

    const transaction = new Transaction({
      feePayer: accountFrom.publicKey,
      ...blockhash,
    }).add(
      SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: accountFrom.publicKey,
        toPubkey: accountTo.publicKey,
        lamports: 10,
      }),
    );
    const message = transaction.compileMessage();
    const fee = (await connection.getFeeForMessage(message, 'confirmed')).value;
```